# Как определить высоту status- и tab-bar для разных разрешений экранов? [Закрыт]

Tags: eclipse, android, java

Подскажите, как узнать высоту `statusbar` и `tabbar` для разных разрешений экранов. Необходимо рассчитать высоту свободного пространства между `status-` и `tabbar`. Не могу понять какие размеры передавать дизайнеру. В источниках нашла только в `pix-ах`, но ведь это значение будет меняться в зависимости от размера экрана...

Comment: пусть сделает для 2-3 экранов, а потом ты сам выставишь это в dp

Comment: s/сам/сама/

Comment: ----пусть сделает для 2-3 экранов, а потом ты сам выставишь это в dp -----Положим, она сделает для 320/480 не учитывая высоту табов, но ведь потом при отображении на экране картинка сама не "подстроится" под "обрезанный" размер,и часть сверху и снизу будет перекрыта?

Comment: KoVadim, непонятен Ваш комментарий.

Comment: надо что бы подстролись сама, изать draw9patch, правильно выставить коэфициент заполнения. В общем сейчас трудно это понять/обьяснить, но как попробуешь пару вариантов - разберешься

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, это головная боль... Как я иногда завидую яблочникам - у них там 2-3 типоразмера на все случаи жизни и все - пиши не хочу. У Android'еров в этом смысле жизнь несладкая.

Изначально предполагается, что размеры лучше всего выражать в `dip`'ах (они же `dp`), но это тоже не всегда работает.

В вашем конкретном случае - у вас есть один точный размер от которого надо отталкиваться: высота строки (которая зависит от выбранного шрифта и стиля). К сожалению высоту строки,  можно узнать только динамически:

```
TextView.getLineHeight()
```

И динамически же менять по ходу пьесы высоту таба/статусбара или чего там у вас.

А дизайнеру скажите, что высота вашего таба будет 1.5 высоты размера шрифта - и пусть дальше дизайнит :)

Comment: Barmaley, это точно!!! Она для apple сделала довольно быстро,а с android-ом началось веселье (((. Не очень понятно где эту строку ----TextView.getLineHeight()----  нужно прописать? У меня названия вкладок вот здесь  -----tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tag3");
  tabSpec.setIndicator("Карта");
  tabSpec.setContent(new Intent(this, MapActivity.class));
  tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);---- ? Расскажите, пожалуйста, подробнее.

Comment: `TextView.getLineHeight()` во время `onCreate()` будет неизвестен - так что смотрите сами куда ее пихать

Comment: 2-3 размера? ифон до 4с - 1, ипад - 2, ифон 5 - 3, ретина - 5, ипад мини - 6 по чуть чуть и у них головной боли добавяется

Comment: А как по другому можно объявить названия вкладок, если не в Tabhost? Получается при объявлении в этом методе только название прописывается и даже TextView и не пахнет. А для того чтобы прописать TextView.getLineHeight(), надо сначала TextView объявить и применить, причём непосредственно к названию вкладок. Так как же правильно это реализовать?

Comment: TextView можно вытянуть из таба методом findById()

Comment: А в чем проблема задать свой View?

Comment: Спасибо! Буду пробовать )))

Comment: @s01nyshko `new TextView()` не пробовала? :)

Comment: @Barmaley,нет не пробовала. Зато подумала над Вашими словами: " у вас есть один точный размер от которого надо отталкиваться" и поняла, что на табах есть иконки, и их размер точно известен, при чём конкретный для разных экранов, - решила от этого и плясать :).

Всем спасибо за отзывчивость!!!